# No me está pintando un campo en una tabla

Tags: php, html

Es muy curioso, pero no se por que para.

No me está pintando un campo en una tabla. Como veis la tabla está mal, falta el campo estado, pero si voy a inspección de la página si, que me lo está pintando ABIERTO es el estado. Es todo copiado de lo mismo que tengo en otra pagina pero en la otra no me falla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 
      <!-- DataTales Example -->
      <div class="card shadow mb-4">
            <div class="card-header py-3">
              <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Incidencias asignadas</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead class="text-center">
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Incidencia</th>
                            <th>Usuario</th>                                
                            <th>Estado</th>
                            <th>Fecha de apertura</th>
                            <th>Departamento</th>
                            <th>Acciones</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Incidencia</th>
                      <th>Usuario</th>
                      <th>Estado</th>
                      <th>Fecha de apertura</th>
                      <th>Departamento</th>
                      <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                    <?php foreach(get_incidencias_admin($conexion) as $dato):?>
                    <tbody>     
                    <tr>
                    <td ><?php echo $dato['id_incidencia']?></td>
                     <td ><?php echo $dato['incidencia']?></td>
                     <td ><?php echo $dato['usuario']?></td>
                     <td ><?php echo $dato['estado']?></td>
                     <td ><?php echo $dato['fecha_inicio']?></td>
                     <td ><?php echo $dato['nom_dep']?></td>
                     <td ><button class="btn btn-primary" ><a style="color: white; text-decoration:none;" href="editar_incidencia.php?id_incidencia=<?php echo $dato['id_incidencia']?>">Ver</a></button></td>
     
                    </tr>
      
                    </tbody>  
                    <?php endforeach ?>      
                </table>       
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué pones un espacio en blanco en las etiquetas `<td >`? Otra cosa que está mal es crear el `tbody` dentro del bucle, deberías abirlo antes del bucle y cerrarlo después (la tabla no tiene tantos `tbody` como filas). Aunque HTML sea permisivo, no abuses, estarías creando un HTML inválido. Corrige eso, sea o no la causa del error... Luego, haz un `var_dump($dato);` dentro del bucle para verificar con qué datos estás trabajando realmente. Puede que no haya ningún valor para `estado` en este contexto, debes depurarlo verificando los datos. ABC de depuración.

Comment: Corregido el código. Hice un var_dump dentro del bucle y me lo imprime bien string(7) "Abierto" string(7) "Abierto" string(7) "Cerrado" string(7) "Cerrado"

Answer (score 0):

He revisado tu código y hay algunos errores; como los espacios que dejas en las celdas de datos tags "td" y tambien hay un error a la hora de colocar el bucle foreach; para que funcione debes colocarlo luego encima de la fila de celdas tr; corrigiendo eso; todo quedaría así:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- DataTales Example -->
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
          <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Incidencias 
asignadas</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" 
cellspacing="0">
                  <thead class="text-center">
                      <tr>
                          <th>ID</th>
                          <th>Incidencia</th>
                          <th>Usuario</th>                                
                          <th>Estado</th>
                          <th>Fecha de apertura</th>
                          <th>Departamento</th>
                          <th>Acciones</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Incidencia</th>
                    <th>Usuario</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                    <th>Fecha de apertura</th>
                    <th>Departamento</th>
                    <th>Acciones</th>
                  </tr>
                </tfoot>
                  
                  <tbody>
                  <?php foreach(get_incidencias_admin($conexion) as $dato):?>     
                  <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $dato['id_incidencia']?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $dato['incidencia']?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $dato['usuario']?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $dato['estado']?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $dato['fecha_inicio']?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $dato['nom_dep']?></td>
                   <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ><a style="color: 
white; text-decoration:none;" href="editar_incidencia.php?id_incidencia=<?php 
echo $dato['id_incidencia']?>">Ver</a></button></td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                  </tbody>    
              </table>       
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como ya senalé en mi comentario, estás poniendo un espacio de más en las etiquetas `<td>`.

Luego, el lugar donde estás poniendo el `tbody` no es correcto. Al ponerlo dentro del bucle, cada fila será un nuevo `tbody` para la tabla. También estás poniendo el `tfoot` antes del principio, algo así como poner la cabeza, los pies y luego el cuerpo.

Intenta de este modo, donde corregimos todo lo antes dicho:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- DataTales Example -->
      <div class="card shadow mb-4">
            <div class="card-header py-3">
              <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Incidencias asignadas</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead class="text-center">
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Incidencia</th>
                            <th>Usuario</th>                                
                            <th>Estado</th>
                            <th>Fecha de apertura</th>
                            <th>Departamento</th>
                            <th>Acciones</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
<?php   
    $rows="";     
    foreach(get_incidencias_admin($conexion) as $dato):
                $rows.="<tr>
                          <td>$dato[id_incidencia]</td>
                          <td>$dato[incidencia]</td>
                          <td>$dato[usuario]</td>
                          <td>$dato[estado]</td>
                          <td>$dato[fecha_inicio]</td>
                          <td>$dato[nom_dep]</td>
                          <td><button class=\"btn btn-primary\"><a style=\"color: white; text-decoration:none;\" href=\"editar_incidencia.php?id_incidencia=$dato[id_incidencia]\">Ver</a></button></td>
                        </tr>";
    endforeach;
    echo $rows;                        
?>      
                    </tbody>  
                    <tfoot>
                      <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Incidencia</th>
                        <th>Usuario</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                        <th>Fecha de apertura</th>
                        <th>Departamento</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                      </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>       
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Si observas, he optado por concatenar todas las filas dentro de una variable `$rows`, lo cual tiene varias ventajas: el código queda más limpio al no tener que abrir/cerrar constantemente bloques de código PHP/HTML; y tendrás la posibilidad de hacer una depuración específica de `$rows` en caso de que siga sin funcionar, pudiendo analizar lo que se estaría produciendo. De modo que si no funciona, pon un `var_dump($rows);` y revisa que todo esté correcto en ese punto (filas y celdas bien construidas). Si tienes los datos ahí, puede que la columna `status` no se muestre debido a alguna regla de estilo que tengas o algo así.

Comment: El código lo corregí como te comenté en el comentario anterior. Lo he cambiado por el tuyo, y sigue sin pintar. Es muy raro por que es una copy/paste de otra tabla que tengo, solo he cambiado la función.

Comment: @Flowcou ¿qué muestra el **`var_dump($rows);`** ? agrégalo a la pregunta para revisarlo.

Comment: string(2006) ""

Comment: @Flowcou hay 2006 caracteres pero no se ven debido al entorno en que está el var_dump, ponlo así, interesa ver el contenido: `echo '<pre>';  var_dump($rows); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: Sigue saliendo lo mismo.

Comment: @Flowcou es muy extraño. Sugiero que inspecciones el código fuente y la consola del navegador para ver si marca algún error. Lo único que se me ocurre es que haya estilos .css que impidan la visualización.

Comment: He encontrado el fallo, tenia en el footer un archivo JS que no sé por qué, impedía que el estado se imprimiese, lo he puesto en otro lugar y ha funcionado.